# How to use conditional statements

Tags: conditional-statements

So I am using this code:

```
//You should replace this "true" with your right condition(in accordance to your logic).
var condition = true;
if(condition){
   //Run create service.
   checkbox.execute();
}
else{
   //Run udpate service.
   check_update.execute();
}
```

I want upon the first time a button is ever clicked to execute checkbox... as it says above. From there on out, I want it to execute check_update.

Any ideas as to what "var condition = true" should be??

Answer (score 0):

How about making a variable that will store whether or not the button has been clicked for the first time yet:

```
var first_time = true;

if (first_time) {
    // Run create service.
    checkbox.execute();

    first_time = false;
} else {
    // Run udpate service.
    check_update.execute();
}
```

If this is Javascript, you'll have to be aware of the scope of this variable as well.

Comment: I don't think that it recognized the first time part of it because I ran the create service repeatedly instead of only once. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @EllenSchlechter if this code is in a function, you'll need to move the variable declartion for `first_time` (the first line), outside of it. Otherwise it is re-declared every time the function is run as `true`. If you can post more of the relevant code it might help.